# AngularJS: Conditionally set min based on other field

Tags: angularjs

I have two input fields: A `select` with `Yes/No` and a `number` input.
When the `select` is **No**, the `number` is disabled and set it to 0. But when the `select` is **Yes**, I would like to set it to a minimum of 1.

```
<body ng-app="KnobDemoApp">
  <div ng-controller="knobCtrl as knob">
    <label>Yes/No:</label>
    <select ng-model="knob.yesno" name="yesnoName" ng-options="x for x in yes_no">
        <option value="" disabled>Select One</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Number:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="numyesno" name="numName"
    ng-disabled="knob.yesno != 'Yes'"
    min="if knob.yesno == 'Yes' then 1 else 0"></input>
    <br><br>
    <span> Value: </span>{{knob.yesno}} <br>
    <span> Check: </span>{{knob.yesno != 'Yes'}}
  </div>
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('KnobDemoApp', [])
app.controller('knobCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.yes_no = ["Yes", "No"];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngChange` to get the `current` value of your `ngModel`, then you can set your `input` to 0 when it's equivalent to *"No"*.

```js
angular
  .module('KnobDemoApp', [])
  .controller('knobCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.setValue = setValue;
    $scope.yes_no = ["Yes", "No"];

    function setValue() {
      if ($scope.knob.yesno === 'No') {
        $scope.numyesno = 0;
      } else {
        $scope.numyesno = 1
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="KnobDemoApp">
  <div ng-controller="knobCtrl as knob">
    <label>Yes/No:</label>
    <select ng-model="knob.yesno"
            name="yesnoName"
            ng-options="x for x in yes_no"
            ng-change="setValue()">
      <option value hidden>Select One</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Number:</label>
    <input type="number"
           ng-model="numyesno"
           name="numName"
           ng-disabled="knob.yesno !== 'Yes'"
           min="{{knob.yesno === 'Yes' ? 1 : ''}}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <span> Value: </span>{{knob.yesno}}
    <br>
    <span> Check: </span>{{knob.yesno != 'Yes'}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try selecting no and again yes. Number is not changing to 1.

Comment: It shouldn't change to 1, `min` in `input type="number"` just means: *restrict the MIN number based on clicks on the arrows, not what the user types*. Please, read the docs.

Comment: I agree,  But, I said that it should change to 1 just as per the requirement here.

Comment: Can be, for me it makes no difference at all, anyway I'll accept your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="numyesno" name="numName" 
       ng-disabled="knob.yesno == 'No'" 
       min="{{(knob.yesno == 'Yes') ? 1 : 0}}" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work; still allows me to set negative numbers in the input

Comment: You are just missing the curlies `{{knob.yesno == 'Yes' ? 1 : 0}}` :)